# Сравнить список с наименованиями и числами в питоне. Найти наименование у которого соответствующее число наивысшее

Tags: python, list

В первом списке имена игроков, во втором списке количество их очков.Нужно найти победителя(того у кого больше всего очков, если у двух игроков одинаковое кол-во наивысших балов, победителем считается первый в списке.

```
my_list = [['Vasya', 'Sasha', 'Kolya', 'Igor'], [5, 4, 3, 4]]
winner = 'Vasya'
my_list2= [['Igor', 'Kolya', 'Petya', 'Sasha'], [4, 6, 6, 3]]
winner2 = 'Kolya'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну например так

```
my_list = [['Vasya', 'Sasha', 'Kolya', 'Igor'], [5, 4, 3, 4]]
winner = my_list[0][my_list[1].index(max(my_list[1]))]
print(winner)

my_list = [['Igor', 'Kolya', 'Petya', 'Sasha'], [4, 6, 6, 3]]
winner = my_list[0][my_list[1].index(max(my_list[1]))]
print(winner)
```

а вообще самому надо для начала пытаться делать школьное задание ;-)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, в следующий раз уже только)

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант:

```
winner = sorted(zip(*my_list), key=lambda x: -x[1])[0][0]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]